# How to properly use QLayouts (hbox, vbox, etc)?

Tags: c++, qt

I am building a custom widget based on `QGraphicsWidget`

Inside the widget, I need various other widgets in line with the size of the window. For this I am using

```
Layout = new QGraphicsLinearLayout();
Layout->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
setLayout(Layout);
```

So I have a layout, and on each side of the layout I have a widget. So a widget on the left side, and a widget on the right side.

```
 QGraphicsLinearLayout() below

      500 px wide x
|--------------------------------| 
|                                |
|left widget         right widget|   100 px tall y
|--------------------------------|
```

I want the behaviour that when the window gets bigger, the widgets stay within x pixels of the edge. So if the window were to be resized to 10,000 pixels wide, left widget would always be 1 pixel from the left edge and right widget would always be 1 pixel from the right edge.

```
                10000 px wide x
|---------------------------------------------------| 
|                                                   |
|left widget                            right widget|   100 px tall y
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

The current behaviour is that left widget will stay in place and never move, and right widget will move away from the right edge.

To achieve this behaviour, I have tried the following:

```
Layout->setAlignment(leftWidget, Qt::AlignLeft);
```

That does absolutely nothing.

I also tried

```
Layout->addItem(leftWidget);

Layout->setStretchFactor(leftWidget, 0);

Layout->addItem(rightWidget);
```

Which gives the desired effect but overlaps the rightWidget with the border like so

```
      500 px wide x
|--------------------------------| 
|                                |
|left widget                 right widget   100 px tall y
|--------------------------------|
```

So how can I get my desired behaviour? QLayouts seem very confusing and the API's misleading thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Use [QGraphicsLinearLayout::addStretch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicslinearlayout.html#addStretch) between the left and right widgets in order to keep them to the sides and [QGraphicsLayout::setContentsMargins](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicslayout.html#setContentsMargins) to add a space between the widgets and the edges:

```
auto *l = new QGraphicsLinearLayout();

l->addItem(leftProxy);
l->addStretch();
l->addItem(rightProxy);
l->setContentsMargins(25, 1, 1, 1);
l->setSpacing(1);
```

## Example

I have prepared a minimal example for you of how to use the proposed solution:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    auto *widget = new QWidget();
    auto *leftWidget = new QPushButton(tr("Left"));
    auto *rightWidget = new QPushButton(tr("Right"));
    auto *leftProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
    auto *rightProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
    auto *l = new QGraphicsLinearLayout();
    auto *sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(widget);

    leftWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    rightWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

    widget->setMinimumSize(sizeGrip->sizeHint().width()
                           + leftWidget->sizeHint().width()
                           + rightWidget->sizeHint().width(),
                           leftWidget->sizeHint().height());

    leftProxy->setWidget(leftWidget);
    rightProxy->setWidget(rightWidget);

    l->addItem(leftProxy);
    l->addStretch();
    l->addItem(rightProxy);
    l->setContentsMargins(25, 1, 1, 1);
    l->setSpacing(1);

    view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
    view->scene()->addWidget(widget)->setLayout(l);

    widget->resize(400, 200);

    setCentralWidget(view);
    resize(640, 480);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, when I resize my widget leftWidget & rightWIdget don't move.

Comment: Isn't addStrect(0) & setStretchFactor(leftWidget, 0) the same thing?

Comment: @IhaveAquestion, no, they are not. And in order to know why this does not work for you and offer you a solution, you have to prepare a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: addStrech(1) gives me the effect I need but it's overdrawing the widget like I described.

Comment: @IhaveAquestion, it would be faster if you show the cause instead of trying to come up with a solution. Prepare a MCVE.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, I will mark as such, but when you're resizing custom widgets there's more to it than this, honestly don't feel like typing it out but this is correct answer. SHort version is that when resizing you must setMin/MaxWidth accordingly on the underlying parent widget and QGraphicsLinearLayout, or else it will stop at the last or initial setMaximumWidth value